# Animation in <p:dataTable> columns. Restricted text to one line in all columns no matter how large the text is

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hope you all will be fine. I have a p:dataTable in which i have columns like this

```
<p:column filterBy="#{Faq.faqCategoryName}"
          headerText="Category"
          filterMatchMode="contains">

    <h:outputText value="#{Faq.faqCategoryName}"
                  style="color: #0d5b7f;" />

</p:column>

<p:column filterBy="#{Faq.question}"
          headerText="Questions"
          filterMatchMode="contains" >

    <h:commandLink value="#{Faq.question}"
                   action="#{faq.viewFaq()}"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;" >

       <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" />

    </h:commandLink>

</p:column>

<p:column filterBy="#{Faq.answer}"
          headerText="Answers"
          filterMatchMode="contains" >

    <h:outputText value="#{Faq.answer}"
                  style="color: #0d5b7f;" />

</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Action" >

    <h:commandLink action="#{faq.updateFaq}"
                   value="Update"
                   title="Update FAQ Category"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline" >

        <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" />

    </h:commandLink>

    <p:spacer width="3" />

    <h:commandLink action="#{faq.deleteFaq(Faq)}"
                   value="Delete"
                   title="Delete FAQ Category"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
                   onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the FAQ?') ) { return false;}; return true; ">

        <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" />

    </h:commandLink>

</p:column>
```

The problem is Questions and Answers column can be as large as possioble. Now what is happening that if the text is large in these columns then it comes to next line in the same column. I want that no matter that how long the text is in these columns, the text never append to next line.

Instead i show ellipsess symbol that indicating that this column has more text and when you mouse hover the column then the box appear that will show the whole text.
I mean to say that all columns should be of one line only. If text is larget , then ellipses shown instead of text appending to next line.
Is this possible ? If yes then how can i do it? Do i need to use jQuery here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is possible!

You could use this simple javascript solution: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/truncate/ (and if you don't like the `onclick` event, you could implement an `onhover` event).

You could use this JQuery solution: http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate.

But also, 'cause you have chosen Primefaces, you could use the **tooltip** component. Combine the javascript solution by truncating the column value and provide the full value to the tooltip (also you could provide that truncated value from the server):

```
<p:column>
   <p:outputText id='myId' value="#{myBean.myTruncatedQuestionValue}" />
   <p:tooltip for="myId" value="#{myBean.myUntruncatedQuestionValue}" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />  
</p:column>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tooltip.jsf

PS: When you say `Hope you all will be fine`, it looks like you're announcing an earthquake...it's sad and it's wrong!

Comment: This is not working                                            [code]<p:column filterBy="#{Faq.question}" headerText="Questions"   filterMatchMode="contains" >
    <h:commandLink id="question" value="#{Faq.partialQuestion}"
          action="#{faq.viewFaq()}" style="color: #0d5b7f;" >
        <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" /> 
    </h:commandLink>

     <p:tooltip for="question" value="#{Faq.question}"
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                             
 </p:column>

Comment: I am using h:commandLink. does p:toolTip works on h:commandlink ?

Comment: @Basit What version of PF do you use? Try `outputlink` instead of `commandLink`

Comment: I am using Prime Faces 2.2. This is working code, but i have another problem. if you see my post then you see i used [code]action="#{faq.viewFaq()}" , means when you click on it then it takes you to another page. The code i am using , there is no action attribute in the <h:outputLink>. How can i use <h:outputLink> to redirect user to another page ? [code]<h:outputLink  id="question" value="#{faq.viewFaq()}" title="#{Faq.question}" style="color: #0d5b7f;">
<h:outputText value="#{Faq.partialQuestion}"/>              <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" />
</h:outputLink>

Comment: @Basit The outputLink `value` is the so called `href`; so the value attribute holds the url. By the way, when you post code and explanation, edit your question and stop using [code] - your comment is unreadable!

Comment: I always wanted to know that how can i post code in the comments, i use [code] because in the tip it is mention like this [link](http://example.com). But [code] doesn't work. Anyways thank you very much for your help :) ;)

Comment: @Basit you could post code in comments by surrounding it with `(the same key with ~) - but it's not a good thing to post code in comments (a lot of it), it's better to edit your question. And by the way, you should start accepting the best answers for your questions...

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
<p:column filterBy="#{Faq.question}"
          headerText="Questions"
          filterMatchMode="contains">

    <h:commandLink  id="question"
                    value="#{Faq.partialQuestion}"
                    title="#{Faq.question}"
                    action="#{faq.viewFaq()}"
                     style="color: #0d5b7f;" >

        <f:param name="id" value="#{Faq.faqId}" />

    </h:commandLink>

    <p:tooltip for="question"
               showEffect="fade"
               hideEffect="fade" />

</p:column>
```

Tooltip uses your title attribute, to show text display on ToolTip.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I've told you...I said to edit your question or ask a new one if you got any more problems.